# Logging procedure, package errors to OS's Syslog

Tags: oracle, logs, solaris

Good day,

Setup: Oracle 11G on Solaris 10 x86

We'd like to capture the errors/failures of our nightly scheduled procedures/ packages in the OS's syslog. That log will then be sent to a remote NMS managed by the NOC who'll alert the on-call personnel. Can and how can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that depends on how exactly you run your "scheduled procedures/ packages".

Comment: A scheduler PL/SQL package manages that. Would like to do something like, `exception
    when others then
      *Write message to OS's syslog here*
      commit;
      raise;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it can be done, the question is, do you really want this?

Scheduler jobs can raise events (put in a queue). You can capture (dequeue) those events using Advanced Queueing. For example:

[Monitoring Job State with Events Raised by the Scheduler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/scheduse008.htm#CHDJHFEC)

[How To Use DBMS_SCHEDULER To Publish Events For Oracle Advanced Queueing (Doc ID 871718.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=871718.1)

Once you have the events and details, you need to write them to syslog. You can do this by using external procedures, for example:

[write to syslog from pl/sql](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2343125)

Or, you could keep it nice and simple, and use the built-in e-mail notification support for Scheduler, for example:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.ADD_JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION (
  job_name   =>  'EOD_JOB',
  recipients =>  'jsmith@example.com, rjones@example.com',
  sender     =>  'do_not_reply@example.com',
  subject    =>  'Scheduler Job Notification-%job_owner%.%job_name%-%event_type%',
  body       =>   '%event_type% occurred at %event_timestamp%. %error_message%',
  events     =>  'JOB_FAILED, JOB_BROKEN, JOB_DISABLED, JOB_SCH_LIM_REACHED');
END;
/
```

[Monitoring Job State with E-mail Notifications](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/scheduse008.htm#CIAIEJEJ)

Comment: Thanks for the response. We need to use the Syslog as the NOC doesn't have a system to scan emails for errors or alert on call via email. I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2343125 Worked perfectly with some tweaking.